# Relative Layouts and Linear Layouts

Tags: android, layout, tabs, android-relativelayout, android-linearlayout

how do i embed a tab layout within a button. My main layout is a linear layout, but i don't know how to program the main activity.java class. Could anybody help me get started this is what my main.java code looks like right now

```
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.content.Intent;


 public class Remote_DocActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {    
     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    //private static final String TAG = "Remote_Doc";

    @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.main);
         View Patient_Button = findViewById(R.id.patientButton);
         Patient_Button.setOnClickListener(this);
         View Doctor_Button = findViewById(R.id.doctorButton);
         Doctor_Button.setOnClickListener(this);
         View About_Option = findViewById(R.id.aboutButton);
         About_Option.setOnClickListener(this);
         View Exit_Option = findViewById(R.id.exit);
         Exit_Option.setOnClickListener(this);

     }
     public void onClick(View v) {
         switch (v.getId()) {
         case R.id.aboutButton:
             Intent i = new Intent(this, About.class);
             startActivity(i);
             break;
         case R.id.exit:
            finish();
            break;
         }
     }

 }
```

Comment: Tab layout within button? what u want is unclear to me, also look at this might be what u want http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

Answer (score 1):

you can create tabs with the help of TabActivity class. You can take help from android-wireless-application-development book's unit 3 chapter 8 example.